# Job scheduling issue

Tags: sas

While scheduling an SAS project through Windows scheduler .I am getting the below error.
'This project file has been migrated from version 4.3. The migration will not be complete until you save this project file with this current version'.

I have both SAS E.g. 4.3 and and SAS E.g. 7.1 installed in my machine.

Is there any way to fix this issues?

Answer (score 2):

SAS Scheduling on Windows works by running VBS code on your machine, which in turn creates VB object based on system configuration. In your case, the system is configured to create VB objects of SAS EG 7.1

The simplest solution is to convert your project to SAS EG 7.1 by opening it in SAS EG 7.1 and then saving it. It will do conversion automatically, you will see a message to that effect.

Re-configuring VB could be done by uninstalling SAS EG 7.1 and repairing SAS EG 4.3.

I don't think it is recommended to have two different versions of SAS EG running on the same machine because of the conflicts that it can.

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: I would also recommend saving a 4.3 backup of the file just in case. SAS EG projects are backwards compatible, but not forwards-compatible. If you have to send the file to a user who has not yet migrated to a later version of EG, they will not be able to open it. We had a fun time figuring that one out when half the company had EG 6.1, and the other half had 7.1